# Android ListView with horizontal scrollview

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I want to implement Horizontal Scrollview in each row of list view with multiple layouts attached to horizontal scrollview for each row. (DYNAMICALLY).

i.e Each row can have 3,4 or 5 layouts attached.

**Problem**: - Everything is fine, the main problem is the 1st row is populating with all the rows data and on scrolling of the list view, data is changing rapidly.

Why this is so ?

**Adapter**

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<String> dataSet;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    private View additionView;
    private LinearLayout subFunctionLayout;
    private TextView tv;
    LinearLayout layoutHolder;


    public ListViewAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 40;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if(convertView==null){
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_scroll_layout, null);
            layoutHolder=(LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.layoutHolder);


            for (int i = 0; i <5; i++) {
                //additionView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inner_layout_file, null);
                subFunctionLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
                subFunctionLayout.setOrientation(android.widget.LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                subFunctionLayout.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(-1,-1));
                // ARGB: Opaque Red
                subFunctionLayout.setBackgroundColor(0x88ff0000);
                tv = new TextView(context);
                tv.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(-1,-2));
                tv.setText("TEXT: " + position);
                // ARGB: Opaque Green
                tv.setBackgroundColor(0x5500ff00);
                subFunctionLayout.addView(tv);
                layoutHolder.addView(subFunctionLayout);
                } 

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }



        return convertView;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView tv_titleExample;
        HorizontalScrollView hzView;
        LinearLayout linear_layout,main_linear_layout;
    }

}
```

**Activity Layout**

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvData"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
</ListView>
```

**MAIN LIST VIEW ROW LAYOUT**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutHolder"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

</LinearLayout>
```

**Custom layout which is to be attached to each row's Horizontal Scrollview**

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/icon"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_marginRight="6.0dip"
android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```